# Detect a speed in android

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

is it possible to detect a speed of a car using GPS or accelerometer in android phone ?

can anyone give me the road map to implement this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using GPS via object of [Location](http://d.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class. There is `getSpeed()` method in this class.

It's very easy to find code of getting location. Check [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/0896fb26b159e9c5?pli=1) for example.

Comment: so that means , if a car is running at X speed then i will able to detect at what speed it is running using getSpeed() ?

Comment: Yes. Speed returns in meters/second.

Comment: Okay and to access the direction i.e. left , right and reverse ? do i need to use accelerometer ?

Comment: With GPS you may get the bearing in degrees via method `getBearing()`  of `Location` object. May be better to use accelerometer for this.

Comment: with getSpeed() is not returning correct I have tested any other way by which we can get the speed of vechile......