# Android: Does getSpeed return the user's speed?

Tags: android, gps

I'm confused. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811920/why-getspeed-always-return-0-on-android) says that getSpeed only returns a value set with setSpeed.

But other sources seem to indicate that getSpeed should actually return a speed. The android docs say that getSpeed "Returns the speed of the device over ground in meters/second." Other sources too seem to say that it works to return the speed of the device, e.g.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/125386

[Detect a speed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497234/detect-a-speed-in-android)

Which is correct? I can't seem to get getSpeed to return a non-zero value, so if it does work, what are some common sticking points that I might be screwing up? I have the manifest set correctly, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Speed calculation uses GPS, so you should use GPS location provider and have GPS satellite fix.

Comment: Ok, I get that. I haven't been able to get getSpeed to return a result with a satellite fix and  provider. Does getSpeed return the speed calculated by the GPS device?

Comment: use double speed = location.getSpeed();