# Using the GPS to capture speed

Tags: java, android, gps, android-4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect a speed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497234/detect-a-speed-in-android)

I am getting into Android development and I would like to start messing around with the GPS and capturing speeds. Is there a way I can easily capture the speed using the gps and display that speed on the screen? Any simple frameworks or built in functions I could use?

Comment: Thank You, I did a search earlier and nothing came up.

Answer (score 29):

You will have to use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) which is used to get user location through GPS, the GPS data that returns includes the speed. You will have to use the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` function of the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html).

To get the speed you will need to do this:

```
int speed = location.getSpeed();
```

which is in m/s, if you need to convert it to km/h use this:

```
int speed=(int) ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
```

if you need to convert it to mph use this:

```
int speed=(int) (location.getSpeed()*2.2369);
```

Answer (score 2):

I thinks there are two ways to achieve this:

Firstly, if you refer the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class in android, you can find out that it has got a method named  `getSpeed`. It says:

```
Returns the speed of the device over ground in meters/second. 
If hasSpeed() is false, 0.0f is returned.
```

So, you may write, something like this

```
if (locationObj.hasSpeed()) {
    float speed = locationObj.getSpeed();
    // process data
} else {
    // Speed information not available.
}
```

Secondly, you may track gps location updates, so that, you store previous location and time at which that update occurs. Now, each time a new update comes you can find the distance travelled using `distanceTo` method of `Location` class. So, to know the current speed, you may use the formula, `distance travelled / time difference between the updates`